# OEM vs. after-market bumper repair: is there a difference in quality?

Tags: body-work

Another vehicle hit mine, and the offending driver has offered to pay for repairs and a rental vehicle. That said, he is being cheap about using OEM vs. after-market parts.

I have noticed that after-market parts are approximately half of the cost of the OEM parts but have been advised that, in some instances, the after-market parts may not fit correctly.

Moreover, I have been told that insurance companies generally require the use of after-market parts for repairs.

My vehicle is a 2006 Acura MDX with white pearlescent paint. Am I going to see a difference in quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated [in this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/how-to-ensure-body-repair-parts-will-fit), if you purchase a bumper cover which is CAPA certified, you'll not have any issues.

Tell the guy you don't care which part he gets to replace (aftermarket or OEM) ***as long as it is CAPA certified*** and you'll not have any issues ... at least with the fit of the bumper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be a difference in quality. They are not necessarily made from the same materials or molds as the OEM parts. Any savings in cost on aftermarket body parts is often made up for by the additional work to get proper fitment and paint quality during install.